# Work with results of tbats decomposition

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, tbats

I made a time series decomposition with tbats. There is weekly and yearly seasonality in the data (and maybe also monthly - not really important for the question)

```
x <- msts(data, start=c(2005,1,1), seasonal.period=c(7,30.4,365.25))
fit <- tbats(x, use.box.cox=FALSE)
plot(fit)
```

[image]

As far as i understand the tbats result is an "additive decomposition", right?

I can now access the different parts of the tbats decomposition:

```
level <- as.numeric(tbats.components(fit)[,'level'])
season1 <- as.numeric(tbats.components(fit)[,'season1'])
season2 <- as.numeric(tbats.components(fit)[,'season2'])
season3 <- as.numeric(tbats.components(fit)[,'season3'])
```

Since i suppressed 'Box-Cox transformation' earlier, level is roughly the same then trend according to a post from Rob J Hyndman  in the comments section here:  [here](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/dailydata/)

In order to get the remainder part of the decomposition is it a legit way to just subtract all the parts from the original data?

```
remainder <- data - level - season1 - season2 - season3
```

What do i get when i use this:

```
y <- resid(fit)
```

I am a bit confused right now about the right way to do it... Many thanks for all your input!

**Update:**

```
resid(fit)
fit$errors
```

Those two are both the same. I guess these values are related to the tbats method. I am doubting that i can take them as the "remainder" of the decomposition? Is there a way to extract the remainder out of the tbats method? In his paper '*Forecasting time series with complex seasonal patterns using exponential smoothing*' Rob J Hyndman shows remainder graphs for the tbats method so that's why i think it is possible to get in R as well.
Anyone any thoughts about that?

Comment: Don't be surprised when you find significant seasonal auto-correlation in your final residuals as we all get what we deserve in the end.

Comment: Thx IrishStat for all your input - i really appreciate it and i learned a lot based on your answers and posts in this forum. Unfortunately i'm a student and in order to pass my project i can not use autobox to get a solution(besides the money aspect). i have to find a way on my own - it will be for sure not the best one - i am aware of that. I try to contribute to this forum in the best way i can - by asking "well" formulated questions and include as much infos as i have so far. let's see where i end, maybe i learn something and maybe i can help the next student who will ask "basic" stuff here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A TBATS model has an ARMA error structure. You are ignoring that when you simply subtract the level and seasonal terms. The `residuals()` function will extract the residuals properly, taking account of the ARMA error structure.